Minimal Faithful Permutation degree of Elementary Abelian 2-groups.
I am interested in the minimal faithful permutation degree, $\mu (G)$, of the elementary abelian 2-groups. I was unable to compute it's value in GAP for SmallGroup(64,267), which is the elementary abelian group, $G=(\mathbb{Z}_2)^6$ (I let it run like 20 minutes with no answer in GAP 4.12.2). I think it's not hard to prove that for an Abelian 2-group, $$\mu (G)\leq 2k$$ where $k$ is the prime-base logarithm of the order (e.g. for the specific group in question here, $k=6$). My question is: Is this bound sharp? (i.e. $\mu (G)=2k$) and if not, what is the value of $\mu (G)$ for the specific group in question.

It appears the answer is affirmative as a consequence of theorem 1.1 here: https://web.archive.org/web/20180722094547id_/https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/6A822D51355B15614592A4F1C543DBC5/S0004972708000956a.pdf/div-class-title-strict-inequalities-for-minimal-degrees-of-direct-products-div.pdf#:~:text=Abstract.%20The%20minimal%20faithful%20permutation%20degree%20%C2%B5(G),that%20G%20embeds%20in%20the%20symmetric%20group

The calculation, BTW, is immediate in GAP 4.13.1

I wondered if perhaps the algorithm had been improved since GAP 4.12.2. Incidentally I was able to get the computation to finish, but it took just over 30 minutes according to the time command, so yea, very slow in older version. (even rank 5 groups of order 64 finish in generally less than 10 seconds in 4.12.2).

@JustinBenfield This change (authored by @ahulpke) improved the algorithm, but was not included in GAP 4.12.2. Among other things, the algorithm now explicitly uses the result you mentioned in your previous comment for abelian groups.
